# Objective C to Java Android

Tags: java, android, objective-c, translate

I have to use an Objective C code and translate it into Java for Android.Actually I've never use Objective C before and it's really gives me headache to translate the code,because it's really different from Java (for me as syntax).Can anyone help me a little with the tranlate or help me to understand what the code is doing..I can't get the idea.

**Thanks in advance!!!**

Here is the code that I need to translate:

**EDIT :**  Code is removed.

Comment: That's the code, I can't give more of it.

Comment: @stoupa - Obviously not. He wants to know what is the idea behind the code. He don't understand well objective-c and the code is quite messy, long and hard to understand.

Comment: @Bombastic - `stoupa` wants to say that you just want someone else to do the job for you. I am sure this is not the case here.

Comment: The idea behind the code is : As I know,the Objective C code get a data stream and trying to separate the stream to packets,but my problem is that this is the first time that I'm working with httpclient in Java and Android,and it's a little hard for me to do it.That's why I have to look at the Objective C code ad trying to translate it in Java. (Благодаря за разяснението колега :) ).

And I don't want someone else to do my job,I just need a little help with the Objective C functions,object and etc..I can't understand which one is Objective C Object or not.

Comment: This method is 241 lines. Also it has some programming crimes like 'case 1,, case 2' and ridiculous comments like '// you baad bad buffer'. Isn't it easier to rewrite it entirely, I doubt that conversion from this code will be stable/bugless.

Comment: Actually as I start reading the code more carefully I understand that If I need to convert that piece of code I need to do convert the rest of the code in file...which is very long.So basically I don't think anyone can help me with that..Thanks anyway for spending your time for reading the question!

Comment: If you are able to debug it, your task will be relatively easy.

Comment: Actually to debug it I need xcode,because this code is a part of IPhone application,which I have to code for Android.But I don't have a mac and xcode,so I'm reading my code in Notepad++ and it's really shitty.Thanks anyway!

Comment: Now this thread is hanging..No one can answer it as there is no code..Anyone close this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure about you requirement. But this might be some help. 
You could convert you obj-c code to c and use the android NDK

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html

The above is an example to call c code from android apps.